# How to scrollLock body when a modal/lightbox is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the lightbox jquery plugin to open a lightbox when a user clicks on a product. Often the lightbox content stretches below the fold, and at the moment the right scrollbar moves the entire page when you scroll down.

I'd like it to work like the pinterest lightbox, whereby the right scrollbar only scrolls the lightbox, and the rest of the page stays fixed. I've seen a few posts on this, but nothing seems to work for me.

Problem is I want the lightbox to scroll if the content is bigger than the viewport of the browser but not the background.

CSS:

```
#lightbox{  position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 100; text-align: center; line-height: 0;}
#lightbox img{ width: auto; height: auto;}
#lightbox a img{ border: none; }

#outerImageContainer{ position: relative; background-color: #fff; width: 250px; height: 250px; margin: 0 auto; }
#imageContainer{ padding: 10px; }

#loading{ position: absolute; top: 40%; left: 0%; height: 25%; width: 100%; text-align: center; line-height: 0; }
#hoverNav{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index: 10; }
#imageContainer>#hoverNav{ left: 0;}
#hoverNav a{ outline: none;}

#prevLink, #nextLink{ width: 49%; height: 100%; background-image: url(data:image2/gif;base64,AAAA); /* Trick IE into showing hover */ display: block; }
#prevLink { left: 0; float: left;}
#nextLink { right: 0; float: right;}
#prevLink:hover, #prevLink:visited:hover { background: url(../images2/prevlabel.gif) left 15% no-repeat; }
#nextLink:hover, #nextLink:visited:hover { background: url(../images2/nextlabel.gif) right 15% no-repeat; }

#imageDataContainer{ font: 10px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; margin: 0 auto; line-height: 1.4em; overflow: auto; width: 100% ; }

#imageData{ padding:0 10px; color: #666; }
#imageData #imageDetails{ width: 70%; float: left; text-align: left; }  
#imageData #caption{ font-weight: bold; }
#imageData #numberDisplay{ display: block; clear: left; padding-bottom: 1.0em;  }           
#imageData #bottomNavClose{ width: 66px; float: right;  padding-bottom: 0.7em; outline: none;}      

#overlay{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 90; width: 100%; height: 500px; background-color: #000; }
```

JS:

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  Lightbox v2.04
//  by Lokesh Dhakar - http://www.lokeshdhakar.com
//  Last Modification: 2/9/08
//
//  For more information, visit:
//  http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
//
//  Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License - http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/
//      - Free for use in both personal and commercial projects
//      - Attribution requires leaving author name, author link, and the license info intact.
//  
//  Thanks: Scott Upton(uptonic.com), Peter-Paul Koch(quirksmode.com), and Thomas Fuchs(mir.aculo.us) for ideas, libs, and snippets.
//          Artemy Tregubenko (arty.name) for cleanup and help in updating to latest ver of proto-aculous.
//
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*

    Table of Contents
    -----------------
    Configuration

    Lightbox Class Declaration
    - initialize()
    - updateImageList()
    - start()
    - changeImage()
    - resizeImageContainer()
    - showImage()
    - updateDetails()
    - updateNav()
    - enableKeyboardNav()
    - disableKeyboardNav()
    - keyboardAction()
    - preloadNeighborImages()
    - end()

    Function Calls
    - document.observe()

*/
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//
//  Configurationl
//
LightboxOptions = Object.extend({
    fileLoadingImage:        'images2/loading.gif',     
    fileBottomNavCloseImage: 'images2/closelabel.gif',

    overlayOpacity: 0.8,   // controls transparency of shadow overlay

    animate: true,         // toggles resizing animations
    resizeSpeed: 7,        // controls the speed of the image resizing animations (1=slowest and 10=fastest)

    borderSize: 10,         //if you adjust the padding in the CSS, you will need to update this variable

    // When grouping images this is used to write: Image # of #.
    // Change it for non-english localization
    labelImage: "Image",
    labelOf: "of"
}, window.LightboxOptions || {});

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var Lightbox = Class.create();

Lightbox.prototype = {
    imageArray: [],
    activeImage: undefined,

    // initialize()
    // Constructor runs on completion of the DOM loading. Calls updateImageList and then
    // the function inserts html at the bottom of the page which is used to display the shadow 
    // overlay and the image container.
    //
    initialize: function() {    

        this.updateImageList();

        this.keyboardAction = this.keyboardAction.bindAsEventListener(this);

        if (LightboxOptions.resizeSpeed > 10) LightboxOptions.resizeSpeed = 10;
        if (LightboxOptions.resizeSpeed < 1)  LightboxOptions.resizeSpeed = 1;

        this.resizeDuration = LightboxOptions.animate ? ((11 - LightboxOptions.resizeSpeed) * 0.15) : 0;
        this.overlayDuration = LightboxOptions.animate ? 0.2 : 0;  // shadow fade in/out duration

        // When Lightbox starts it will resize itself from 250 by 250 to the current image dimension.
        // If animations are turned off, it will be hidden as to prevent a flicker of a
        // white 250 by 250 box.
        var size = (LightboxOptions.animate ? 250 : 1) + 'px';


        // Code inserts html at the bottom of the page that looks similar to this:
        //
        //  <div id="overlay"></div>
        //  <div id="lightbox">
        //      <div id="outerImageContainer">
        //          <div id="imageContainer">
        //              <img id="lightboxImage">
        //              <div style="" id="hoverNav">
        //                  <a href="#" id="prevLink"></a>
        //                  <a href="#" id="nextLink"></a>
        //              </div>
        //              <div id="loading">
        //                  <a href="#" id="loadingLink">
        //                      <img src="images/loading.gif">
        //                  </a>
        //              </div>
        //          </div>
        //      </div>
        //      <div id="imageDataContainer">
        //          <div id="imageData">
        //              <div id="imageDetails">
        //                  <span id="caption"></span>
        //                  <span id="numberDisplay"></span>
        //              </div>
        //              <div id="bottomNav">
        //                  <a href="#" id="bottomNavClose">
        //                      <img src="images/close.gif">
        //                  </a>
        //              </div>
        //          </div>
        //      </div>
        //  </div>


        var objBody = $$('body')[0];

        objBody.appendChild(Builder.node('div',{id:'overlay'}));

        objBody.appendChild(Builder.node('div',{id:'lightbox'}, [
            Builder.node('div',{id:'outerImageContainer'}, 
                Builder.node('div',{id:'imageContainer'}, [
                    Builder.node('img',{id:'lightboxImage'}), 
                    Builder.node('div',{id:'hoverNav'}, [
                        Builder.node('a',{id:'prevLink', href: '#' }),
                        Builder.node('a',{id:'nextLink', href: '#' })
                    ]),
                    Builder.node('div',{id:'loading'}, 
                        Builder.node('a',{id:'loadingLink', href: '#' }, 
                            Builder.node('img', {src: LightboxOptions.fileLoadingImage})
                        )
                    )
                ])
            ),
            Builder.node('div', {id:'imageDataContainer'},
                Builder.node('div',{id:'imageData'}, [
                    Builder.node('div',{id:'imageDetails'}, [
                        Builder.node('span',{id:'caption'}),
                        Builder.node('span',{id:'numberDisplay'})
                    ]),
                    Builder.node('div',{id:'bottomNav'},
                        Builder.node('a',{id:'bottomNavClose', href: '#' },
                            Builder.node('img', { src: LightboxOptions.fileBottomNavCloseImage })
                        )
                    )
                ])
            )
        ]));


        $('overlay').hide().observe('click', (function() { this.end(); }).bind(this));
        $('lightbox').hide().observe('click', (function(event) { if (event.element().id == 'lightbox') this.end(); }).bind(this));
        $('outerImageContainer').setStyle({ width: size, height: size });
        $('prevLink').observe('click', (function(event) { event.stop(); this.changeImage(this.activeImage - 1); }).bindAsEventListener(this));
        $('nextLink').observe('click', (function(event) { event.stop(); this.changeImage(this.activeImage + 1); }).bindAsEventListener(this));
        $('loadingLink').observe('click', (function(event) { event.stop(); this.end(); }).bind(this));
        $('bottomNavClose').observe('click', (function(event) { event.stop(); this.end(); }).bind(this));

        var th = this;
        (function(){
            var ids = 
                'overlay lightbox outerImageContainer imageContainer lightboxImage hoverNav prevLink nextLink loading loadingLink ' + 
                'imageDataContainer imageData imageDetails caption numberDisplay bottomNav bottomNavClose';   
            $w(ids).each(function(id){ th[id] = $(id); });
        }).defer();
    },

    //
    // updateImageList()
    // Loops through anchor tags looking for 'lightbox' references and applies onclick
    // events to appropriate links. You can rerun after dynamically adding images w/ajax.
    //
    updateImageList: function() {   
        this.updateImageList = Prototype.emptyFunction;

        document.observe('click', (function(event){
            var target = event.findElement('a[rel^=lightbox]') || event.findElement('area[rel^=lightbox]');
            if (target) {
                event.stop();
                this.start(target);
            }
        }).bind(this));
    },

    //
    //  start()
    //  Display overlay and lightbox. If image is part of a set, add siblings to imageArray.
    //
    start: function(imageLink) {    

        $$('select', 'object', 'embed').each(function(node){ node.style.visibility = 'hidden' });

        // stretch overlay to fill page and fade in
        var arrayPageSize = this.getPageSize();
        $('overlay').setStyle({ width: arrayPageSize[0] + 'px', height: arrayPageSize[1] + 'px' });

        new Effect.Appear(this.overlay, { duration: this.overlayDuration, from: 0.0, to: LightboxOptions.overlayOpacity });

        this.imageArray = [];
        var imageNum = 0;       

        if ((imageLink.rel == 'lightbox')){
            // if image is NOT part of a set, add single image to imageArray
            this.imageArray.push([imageLink.href, imageLink.title]);         
        } else {
            // if image is part of a set..
            this.imageArray = 
                $$(imageLink.tagName + '[href][rel="' + imageLink.rel + '"]').
                collect(function(anchor){ return [anchor.href, anchor.title]; }).
                uniq();

            while (this.imageArray[imageNum][0] != imageLink.href) { imageNum++; }
        }

        // calculate top and left offset for the lightbox 
        var arrayPageScroll = document.viewport.getScrollOffsets();
        var lightboxTop = arrayPageScroll[1] + (document.viewport.getHeight() / 10);
        var lightboxLeft = arrayPageScroll[0];
        this.lightbox.setStyle({ top: lightboxTop + 'px', left: lightboxLeft + 'px' }).show();

        this.changeImage(imageNum);
    },

    //
    //  changeImage()
    //  Hide most elements and preload image in preparation for resizing image container.
    //
    changeImage: function(imageNum) {   

        this.activeImage = imageNum; // update global var

        // hide elements during transition
        if (LightboxOptions.animate) this.loading.show();
        this.lightboxImage.hide();
        this.hoverNav.hide();
        this.prevLink.hide();
        this.nextLink.hide();
        // HACK: Opera9 does not currently support scriptaculous opacity and appear fx
        this.imageDataContainer.setStyle({opacity: .0001});
        this.numberDisplay.hide();      

        var imgPreloader = new Image();

        // once image is preloaded, resize image container


        imgPreloader.onload = (function(){
            this.lightboxImage.src = this.imageArray[this.activeImage][0];
            this.resizeImageContainer(imgPreloader.width, imgPreloader.height);
        }).bind(this);
        imgPreloader.src = this.imageArray[this.activeImage][0];
    },

    //
    //  resizeImageContainer()
    //
    resizeImageContainer: function(imgWidth, imgHeight) {

        // get current width and height
        var widthCurrent  = this.outerImageContainer.getWidth();
        var heightCurrent = this.outerImageContainer.getHeight();

        // get new width and height
        var widthNew  = (imgWidth  + LightboxOptions.borderSize * 2);
        var heightNew = (imgHeight + LightboxOptions.borderSize * 2);

        // scalars based on change from old to new
        var xScale = (widthNew  / widthCurrent)  * 100;
        var yScale = (heightNew / heightCurrent) * 100;

        // calculate size difference between new and old image, and resize if necessary
        var wDiff = widthCurrent - widthNew;
        var hDiff = heightCurrent - heightNew;

        if (hDiff != 0) new Effect.Scale(this.outerImageContainer, yScale, {scaleX: false, duration: this.resizeDuration, queue: 'front'}); 
        if (wDiff != 0) new Effect.Scale(this.outerImageContainer, xScale, {scaleY: false, duration: this.resizeDuration, delay: this.resizeDuration}); 

        // if new and old image are same size and no scaling transition is necessary, 
        // do a quick pause to prevent image flicker.
        var timeout = 0;
        if ((hDiff == 0) && (wDiff == 0)){
            timeout = 100;
            if (Prototype.Browser.IE) timeout = 250;   
        }

        (function(){
            this.prevLink.setStyle({ height: imgHeight + 'px' });
            this.nextLink.setStyle({ height: imgHeight + 'px' });
            this.imageDataContainer.setStyle({ width: widthNew + 'px' });

            this.showImage();
        }).bind(this).delay(timeout / 1000);
    },

    //
    //  showImage()
    //  Display image and begin preloading neighbors.
    //
    showImage: function(){
        this.loading.hide();
        new Effect.Appear(this.lightboxImage, { 
            duration: this.resizeDuration, 
            queue: 'end', 
            afterFinish: (function(){ this.updateDetails(); }).bind(this) 
        });
        this.preloadNeighborImages();
    },

    //
    //  updateDetails()
    //  Display caption, image number, and bottom nav.
    //
    updateDetails: function() {

        // if caption is not null
        if (this.imageArray[this.activeImage][1] != ""){
            this.caption.update(this.imageArray[this.activeImage][1]).show();
        }

        // if image is part of set display 'Image x of x' 
        if (this.imageArray.length > 1){
            this.numberDisplay.update( LightboxOptions.labelImage + ' ' + (this.activeImage + 1) + ' ' + LightboxOptions.labelOf + '  ' + this.imageArray.length).show();
        }

        new Effect.Parallel(
            [ 
                new Effect.SlideDown(this.imageDataContainer, { sync: true, duration: this.resizeDuration, from: 0.0, to: 1.0 }), 
                new Effect.Appear(this.imageDataContainer, { sync: true, duration: this.resizeDuration }) 
            ], 
            { 
                duration: this.resizeDuration, 
                afterFinish: (function() {
                    // update overlay size and update nav
                    var arrayPageSize = this.getPageSize();
                    this.overlay.setStyle({ height: arrayPageSize[1] + 'px' });
                    this.updateNav();
                }).bind(this)
            } 
        );
    },

    //
    //  updateNav()
    //  Display appropriate previous and next hover navigation.
    //
    updateNav: function() {

        this.hoverNav.show();               

        // if not first image in set, display prev image button
        if (this.activeImage > 0) this.prevLink.show();

        // if not last image in set, display next image button
        if (this.activeImage < (this.imageArray.length - 1)) this.nextLink.show();

        this.enableKeyboardNav();
    },

    //
    //  enableKeyboardNav()
    //
    enableKeyboardNav: function() {
        document.observe('keydown', this.keyboardAction); 
    },

    //
    //  disableKeyboardNav()
    //
    disableKeyboardNav: function() {
        document.stopObserving('keydown', this.keyboardAction); 
    },

    //
    //  keyboardAction()
    //
    keyboardAction: function(event) {
        var keycode = event.keyCode;

        var escapeKey;
        if (event.DOM_VK_ESCAPE) {  // mozilla
            escapeKey = event.DOM_VK_ESCAPE;
        } else { // ie
            escapeKey = 27;
        }

        var key = String.fromCharCode(keycode).toLowerCase();

        if (key.match(/x|o|c/) || (keycode == escapeKey)){ // close lightbox
            this.end();
        } else if ((key == 'p') || (keycode == 37)){ // display previous image
            if (this.activeImage != 0){
                this.disableKeyboardNav();
                this.changeImage(this.activeImage - 1);
            }
        } else if ((key == 'n') || (keycode == 39)){ // display next image
            if (this.activeImage != (this.imageArray.length - 1)){
                this.disableKeyboardNav();
                this.changeImage(this.activeImage + 1);
            }
        }
    },

    //
    //  preloadNeighborImages()
    //  Preload previous and next images.
    //
    preloadNeighborImages: function(){
        var preloadNextImage, preloadPrevImage;
        if (this.imageArray.length > this.activeImage + 1){
            preloadNextImage = new Image();
            preloadNextImage.src = this.imageArray[this.activeImage + 1][0];
        }
        if (this.activeImage > 0){
            preloadPrevImage = new Image();
            preloadPrevImage.src = this.imageArray[this.activeImage - 1][0];
        }

    },

    //
    //  end()
    //
    end: function() {
        this.disableKeyboardNav();
        this.lightbox.hide();
        new Effect.Fade(this.overlay, { duration: this.overlayDuration });
        $$('select', 'object', 'embed').each(function(node){ node.style.visibility = 'visible' });
    },

    //
    //  getPageSize()
    //
    getPageSize: function() {

         var xScroll, yScroll;

        if (window.innerHeight && window.scrollMaxY) {  
            xScroll = window.innerWidth + window.scrollMaxX;
            yScroll = window.innerHeight + window.scrollMaxY;
        } else if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight){ // all but Explorer Mac
            xScroll = document.body.scrollWidth;
            yScroll = document.body.scrollHeight;
        } else { // Explorer Mac...would also work in Explorer 6 Strict, Mozilla and Safari
            xScroll = document.body.offsetWidth;
            yScroll = document.body.offsetHeight;
        }

        var windowWidth, windowHeight;

        if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
            if(document.documentElement.clientWidth){
                windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth; 
            } else {
                windowWidth = self.innerWidth;
            }
            windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
        } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) { // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
            windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
            windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
        }   

        // for small pages with total height less then height of the viewport
        if(yScroll < windowHeight){
            pageHeight = windowHeight;
        } else { 
            pageHeight = yScroll;
        }

        // for small pages with total width less then width of the viewport
        if(xScroll < windowWidth){  
            pageWidth = xScroll;        
        } else {
            pageWidth = windowWidth;
        }

        return [pageWidth,pageHeight];
    }
}

document.observe('dom:loaded', function () { new Lightbox(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a class that'll allow you to do just that:

```
class ScrollLock {
  constructor () {
    this.pageBody = document.querySelector('body');
    this.scrollY = 0;
  }

  saveScrollY = (num) => {
    this.scrollY = num;
  }

  setScrollY = (num) => {
    window.scroll(0, num);
  }

  setScrollOffset = (vOffset) => {
    this.pageBody.style.top = `-${vOffset}px`;
  }

  freezeBodyScroll = () => {
    this.saveScrollY(window.scrollY);
    this.setScrollOffset(this.scrollY);
    this.pageBody.classList.add('is-fixed');
  }

  unfreezeBodyScroll = () => {
    this.pageBody.classList.remove('is-fixed');

    // Don't reset scroll position if lock hasn't occurred
    if (this.scrollY === 0) return;
    this.setScrollOffset(0);
    this.setScrollY(this.scrollY);
    this.saveScrollY(0);
  }
}
```

Include the following style declaration:

```
// In your CSS
body.is-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

**Use:**

```
const { freezeBodyScroll, unfreezeBodyScroll } = new ScrollLock();

// Call when you open your modal
freezeBodyScroll();

// Call when you close your modal
unfreezeBodyScroll();
```

Comment: Hello, thx for responding but you lost me. Sorry...Where exactly am I including this code? Am I adding your code into the lightbox.css file? What about the const  { code?

Comment: Umm, I'm not sure I can be much more explicit.  Basically, add the above class to your project, then call `freeze/unfreeze` on any events that you wish to freeze/unfreeze the body scroll.  If that doesn't make sense, you might need to brush up on your basic javascript/jquery

Comment: Sorry, I'm a code newbie that's why I'm using a plug-n-play script. I get now what you are saying but what about the last Use: section?

Comment: No sweat.  How are you opening/closing the modal?  Is there a piece of jQuery you're explicitly calling, or does the plugin just look for a specific class/id?

Comment: Do you think you can help me out?

Comment: You'll need to figure out the click handlers that are responsible for showing and hiding your modal, then attach the above methods to them.  If that doesn't make sense, I'm afraid I can't help ya.  Maybe spend a bit of time doing some JavaScript tutorials.

Comment: This is where I grabbed the script from: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/