# How to disable scroll when a div is shown?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I want to disable page scrolling when a div is shown, because its a gallery and scrolling would ruin its functionality.

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                if($("#lightbox").css('display') == 'none') {
                    console.log("not hidden");
                    document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
                } else if($("#lightbox").css('display') == 'block') {
                    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
                    console.log("hidden");
                }
            });
```

I can see "not hidden" in the console which means the function works, but it does not hide the scroll when i click to open the gallery (show the div). I have tried using only else, same thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165859/how-to-scrolllock-body-when-a-modal-lightbox-is-open

Comment: @DanPhilip I can't provide a fiddle since there are multiple files and js libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The code inside:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

means your page is fully loaded, it will be executed, and it is a 1-time event only.

So you have to bind an event when you click the "Open the Galery" button, check the status of your `lightbox`:

```
$("#openGaleryId").click(function(){
    if($("#lightbox").css('display') == 'none') {
       console.log("not hidden");
       document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
    } else if($("#lightbox").css('display') == 'block') {
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        console.log("hidden");
    }
});
```

Comment: I've binded as `$(".gallery").click` which comes from `<li><a href="css/art1.jpg" class="gallery" data-lightbox="portfolio"><img src="css/art1.jpg" class="art" /></a>` but nothing happens.

Comment: I think there is a problem with `if($("#lightbox").css('display') == 'none')` statement since the console shows that the div exists but the source code states `display: none;`. Maybe i should write the statement differently, but how would i do that.

Comment: Maybe this event gets fired before the `#lightbox` got changed.